# Not able to see the log in interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I tried to implement interceptors but it is not working. My project has various lazy loading modules but I have implemented in `app.module.ts` only. Also I checked `HttpClientModule`. It is imported in the `app.module.ts` only, not in other places.

Interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorTest implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, 
             next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
                console.log("Intercepting...");
                return next.handle(req);
    } 

}
`
```

Implementation in app`.module.ts`

```
providers: [{provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass:AuthInterceptorTest, multi:true}]
```

Is there anything missed in the implementation or code?

Comment: I used your code in my project it works fine.

Comment: as a classic: did you try close and open :) maybe reset the editor or npm install

Comment: @AbdurrahmanY I tried that too. But no luck :-(

Comment: Can you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I did it. The root cause is i used `Http` instead of `HttpClient` in the service files. I changed the all API service method as `HttpClient`. Now it's working fine. Thanks @AbdurrahmanY